# Why wont this sql server CE command work?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-ce

I have the command:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_media
(DateAdded) VALUES (GetDate()) 
SELECT CAST(@@Identity AS int)
```

It works fine against a standard sql db but not against a CE db I get the following error:

SQL Execution Error.

```
Executed SQL statement...
Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
Error Message: There was an error parsing the query. [Token line number = 2, Token line offset = 31, Token in error = )]
```

Shame the error isn't more useful anyone know what could be going on?

Cheers

UPDATE::::::

After much messing around with visual studio editor (rubbish) I downloaded dataport and read the MSDN. It seems there are 2 problems...

1) SELECT CAST(@@Identity AS int)  is not valid sql

SELECT @@Identity is

2) SqlCe server does not like it when I put these two commands together:

INSERT INTO tbl_media 
(DateAdded) VALUES (getdate()) 
SELECT @@Identity

If I do the insert and select at different times then it works. So how do I get round this? I cant do it at different times I need to know the ID of the objects as I create them!!!

UPDATE 2:

According to the very helpful Erik E you cant do 2 statements at the same time. So the following parses as correct but wont work:

INSERT INTO tbl_media 
(DateAdded) VALUES (getdate());
SELECT @@Identity;

So what I really want to know is how do I guarantee that identities wont get mixed up when adding records?

I.e. what if someone creates a record while someone is getting the identity for one they have just inserted?

Comment: The error does say line 2 offset 31 token in error = )

Comment: @Pete2K after removing the `)` is this now working, please provide some feedback so we know whether this is still an issue or can be closed?

Comment: No its not im going to update my answer

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra ) I dont know if that will fix your error but look at VALUES you have

`VALUES(GETDATE()))` '<-- one ) extra.

Change it to this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_media(DateAdded) 
VALUES (GetDate()) 
SELECT CAST(@@Identity AS int)
```

Comment: @Pete2k - time to start tearing it apart, it isn't much.  First start with only your INSERT statement, does that alone work?  If that works we know its a problem with the SELECT?

Comment: If the first part works alone, try the second part (the select cast..) alone.  If they work seperately then it looks like @ErikEJ above hit the nail on the headd.

Answer (score 0):

You can only run a single SQL statement per ExecuteNonQuery call. So you must spilt in 2 calls.

Comment: Hi Erik thanks for helping again, however what if another user (from the one inserting the record) inserts a row before I have had a chance to insert 'this' users data record?, doesnt that mean the user could accidentally get the ID for another users record?

Comment: @Pete2k - Yes that could potentially happen.

Comment: then how are you mean to ensure that it doesnt? I mean how can you ever add something to a database and know if youve added it correctly when you for example post a form back?

Comment: SQL Server Compact is not a multi-user database, it only runs on a single computer, and if you wrap the 2 calls in a SqlCeTransaction, there will be no potential for this to happen.